# What are the differences between viXra.org and arXiv.org?

Tags: arxiv, preprint

What are the differences between [viXra.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ViXra) and [arXiv.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArXiv)?

Comment: The answer of your question is here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37976/what-are-pre-print-repositories-for-math-and-physics-alternative-to-arxiv

Comment: To anybody who does not know: The purpose of a pre-print repository is to: 1. Accept any paper and give it a timestamp so that the author can prove precedence of their idea and avoid it being scooped. 2. Allow the author to share the paper on the pre-print repository and invite opinions from colleagues before submitting the paper for peer review. 
Every pre-print repository has to honor these requirements. It is not the job of a pre-print repository to judge a paper by its content (unless it is seriously objectionable content).

Comment: @Julia No, not every preprint repository has to honor those requirements, unless there's some universal agreement on the meaning of "preprint repository" that I'm not aware of. The word "preprint" implies that a preprint repository is a place where papers can appear prior to being "printed", i.e. published in a conventional sense, but otherwise different repositories can choose different sets of policies. In particular, a particular preprint repository could certainly judge a paper by its content if the people running it want to. TBH, I think this is not the place for that discussion.

Comment: One is like your inbox and the other like your spam folder.

Comment: @Julia there are quite a few preprint servers run by departments or small research groups. They clearly filter for (i) who submits a preprint and (ii) that it stays on topic. Of course, quality assurance is only by social pressure there.

Comment: [TechRxiv](https://www.techrxiv.org/) is another.

Answer (score 100):

From [arXiv's website](https://arxiv.org/help/general):

> Started in August 1991, arXiv.org (formerly xxx.lanl.gov) is a highly-automated electronic archive and distribution server for research articles. Covered areas include physics, mathematics, computer science, nonlinear sciences, quantitative biology, quantitative finance, statistics, electrical engineering and systems science, and economics. arXiv is maintained and operated by the Cornell University Library with guidance from the arXiv Scientific Advisory Board and the arXiv Member Advisory Board, and with the help of numerous subject moderators.

arXiv has a form of moderation. Users must be "endorsed" by people who have themselves posted papers on the arXiv. [(more info)](https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement) Moreover, a team of moderators is able to reclassify or remove content from the arXiv, for a number of reasons: unrefereeable content, inappropriate format, inappropriate topic... [(more info)](https://arxiv.org/help/moderation) It also implements some automatic checks for content overlap between papers.

In some fields (e.g. math) it is the standard way of releasing a new paper into the world. At the moment there are 1,369,674 papers on arXiv.

arXiv has a [plan to ensure its sustainability](https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/arxivpub/2018-2022%3A+Sustainability+Plan+for+Classic+arXiv) and make sure that papers uploaded to arXiv will not disappear from the internet should anything bad happens. There also exists several mirror websites should it even go down.

---

From [viXra's website](http://vixra.org/) (in the footer):

> ViXra.org is an e-print archive set up as an alternative to the popular arXiv.org service owned by Cornell University. It has been founded by scientists who find they are unable to submit their articles to arXiv.org because of Cornell University's policy of endorsements and moderation designed to filter out e-prints that they consider inappropriate.
>   ViXra is an open repository for new scientific articles. It does not endorse e-prints accepted on its website, neither does it review them against criteria such as correctness or author's credentials.

It was founded by a disgruntled physicist named Philip Gibbs. It is [unclear who funds the website today](http://vixra.org/funding), and it is not even clear who actually runs it today if you just read the website. Compared to arXiv, there is little moderation ([according to the FAQ](http://vixra.org/faq), a paper can e.g. be removed if it's not science/math, if it's plagiarism, if it's obscene and so on, but not if it is obvious nonsense unless it is computer-generated nonsense) and people can submit papers anonymously or under fake names.

At the moment, there are 22,596 papers on viXra.

viXra has no sustainability plans. If whoever runs it decides to take it down tomorrow or their servers catch fire, I'm not sure what would happen.

Warranted or not, it has a reputation of being an alternative to arXiv for [cranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_(person)) and to host a lot of junk science, fake proofs or even outright nonsense. It is not recommended to submit something to viXra if you wish to be taken seriously, because the reputation of viXra would probably taint your paper's reputation by association. (Which is not the same thing as saying that arXiv "bestows credibility" on papers found there. It's rather viXra which bestows a bad reputation.)

Answer (score 57):

arXiv.org is a multi-institutional e-print repository funded by universities and other research organisations costing hundreds of thousands of dollars to run. It's purpose is rapid dissemination of papers and to provide a permanent open access archive for the professional research community. Submission of papers is in principle open to anyone but those outside the academic world are hampered by a need to be endorsed by an insider. Even when endorsed, papers that do not come from a respected institution are subjected to a moderation process that can result in them being delayed, rejected or reclassified in a generic subject category that may limit how well they are disseminated. The moderation process can sometimes affect professional researchers too if their paper is flagged up by a keyword filter. (Note that it is not known if the institution is used directly by the filter as a criterion but the effect seems to be as stated)

viXra.org is an independent repository intended to cater for those who find it difficult or impossible to submit to arXiv.org or who do not like having their work delayed. It does not require endorsement and there is no moderation process. Some papers may be removed for technical reasons but there is no minimum quality standard. Like arXiv.org its purpose is rapid dissemination and open archiving.

viXra.org is funded by a small group of administrators who run it (including myself) The costs are now so low that funding is barely worth mentioning. It main site runs from a standard GoDaddy web hosting service with another similar mirror site elsewhere. The whole process is almost entirely automated with intervention only being required to respond to occasional emails or technical hiccups. Although its future is not as well assured as arXiv.org it does have a decentralised architecture and replicated shared cloud storage that should make it possible to pass control from one administrator to another when necessary. In my opinion there is a much bigger problem of loss of research papers as small journals come and go but nobody worries about that. viXra already survived an incident where its main server died with a disk failure by quickly re-pointing the DNS to its mirror site. At the time it was using a dedicated server but it was subsequently moved to a virtual server that provides far better robustness at lower cost.

The typical quality of papers on viXra.org is lower than that of arXiv.org because of its open submission policy and because many of its users are independent researchers. However, viXra does have a core of good respectable papers from a diverse range of authors. Many people who look at viXra.org underestimate the amount of quality research it contains because the technical and diverse nature of papers mean that the good ones are only understood and appreciated by specialists while anyone can recognise the low quality content.

Some people advise not to use viXra.org because authors who submit there are "not taken seriously." This misses the point that the purpose of a repository is dissemination and archiving. No repository can bestow credibility on the papers it contains. This can only be done through peer-review, citations, experimental verification etc. Obviously the repository does not discredit a paper either, except in the minds of fools. Should we think that everyone who posts comments on twitter is an idiot just because some others are? I think not. Even arXiv.org does not claim to provide peer-review and most of its papers are only checked for quality by a dumb automated filter. This is why papers on arXiv.org are not automatically considered reliable sources in Wikipedia for example. Even though there is a significant difference between average quality levels on arXiv and viXra, it is still more reliable and easier to judge the quality of a paper in a repository by looking at it rather than by looking at where it is stored.

Some academics strongly disapprove of viXra.org. I think the main reason for this is that they tire of receiving unsolicited emails from "cranks" which they also associate with viXra. The situation is ironic because in fact it is the arXiv endorsement policy that is implicitly encouraging people to try to contact academics in order to get recognition and an endorsement. viXra.org discourages this because it is better and safer to make research available publicly than to send it to people privately. However, viXra.org has no means to police the habits of the minority who ignore this advice.

viXra.org does have some popular features that arXiv.org does not including commenting, download statistics and easy withdrawal or removal of old versions.

Comment: +1 for *This misses the point that the purpose of a repository is dissemination and archiving.* Actually, I believe I gave the first upvote, and now there are 12 upvotes. Buried three or four links into my comment elsewhere in this thread is this [1 June 2011 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7475298) (see "However, a close reading ..."), which partly explains my slight endorsement of this endeavor despite [this comment of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105236/how-to-review-bogus-science-without-hurting-feelings/105240#comment276555_105240).

Comment: Do you have some sort of source for the claim that the moderation process is different based on where the paper comes from? I have been using my private email on arXiv for some time, and it has not seemed any different (though that is of course completely anecdotal).

Comment: They don't give much info on how the filter process works. It may be that independents get caught more because of the way they write their papers. However they also ask for institutional affiliation at some point so that may override email address.

Comment: Sometime I wonder what is your feeling about seeing it be avoided like this? I know that you know that they have their right to say, and you have your right to ignore that, but still what do you really feel?

Comment: @Ooker thank you for asking that. It does not really bother me at all. I know a lot more people could use viXra but don't because they worry about reputation. It is their choice. viXra is there for people who need it. I try to respond to these questions when I find them and defend viXra when I can, but I won't enter into long arguments about it. viXra is not a commercial enterprise so I have nothing to gain from higher usage. As you say, everyone has a right to their opinion.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer but disagree with the last paragraph: "viXra.org does have some popular features that arXiv.org does not including commenting, download statistics and easy withdrawal or removal of old versions." The reason arxiv does not allow to completely withdraw old versions is that should a priority debate happen, people will know that arxiv timestamps are reliable. Allowing complete withdrawal would crush arxiv's dependability in such situation. It a bug, not a feature, in my opinion. Though possibly vixra has different goals in this regard.

Comment: In Europe we have the "right to be forgotten" laws which means that providing the withdrawal feature is legally necessary. It does not undermine the timestamps at all. If someone withdraws they will loose their own priority and are warned of this, but other timestamps are still reliable. When I submit to arXiv my submissions are put on hold for up to two weeks and can be given a later timestamp if accepted. This is a much bigger problem for priority. I rarely use arXiv now for that reason, and never as a first place to post.

Comment: Regarding my first comment to this question (Mar 17 '18), I happened to notice that the first link is now a dead URL. Using the Internet Archive's [wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/), the following has a non-dead link: *... is this* [*1 June 2011 sci.math post*](https://web.archive.org/web/20161206232233/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7475298) *(see "However, a close reading ..."), which partly explains my slight endorsement of this endeavor despite ...*

Answer (score 37):

arXiv is a respected repository for physics and math preprints.  In some fields of physics, it is actually the primary venue through which new papers are read.

viXra is a site for people, almost exclusively cranks, who cannot or will not put their material on arXiv.  Don't use it.

Comment: I have found at least one paper on viXra referenced by no less than Knuth, namely [this one by Philip Gibbs](http://vixra.org/abs/1508.0085). (“This program is based on some beautiful ideas due to Philip E. Gibbs, whose Java code in 2015 was first to beat the billion-number barrier. […] And it has some interesting touches that taught me some lessons, which I'm keen to pass on to others.”) So there exists at least one non-worthless thing on viXra.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR That's true, and nobody is (or should be) disputing the fact that you _can_ find good work on viXra. But the issue is reputation: if you have an arbitrary paper, which you may not necessarily understand, and you find out that it appears on arXiv or on viXra, how does that modify your opinion of that paper? If you're like most researchers, for arXiv, it is unlikely to lower your opinion, but for viXra, it very well could.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: A few weeks ago, entirely by accident, I found by googling various words and phrases [this fairly decent paper on viXra](http://vixra.org/pdf/1102.0058v1.pdf) (reference **[18]** in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584777/irrationality-of-pi2-and-pi3)). Nonetheless, besides this paper and my comment yesterday [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37976/what-are-pre-print-repositories-for-math-and-physics-alternative-to-arxiv/38597#comment277359_38597), I've never seen anything of even remote significance the several times I've looked there.

Comment: @SolarMike: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157250/spotting-crankery

Comment: Do you have a source with your statements?

Comment: @DaveLRenfro (and `@DavidZ` too though I can't tag multiple people): Yes I agree, and that matches my experience too, and in fact the author Philip Gibbs of the cited paper I mentioned appears to be the person who runs vixra.org, so is not exactly the typical uploader to viXra (see his answer to this question).

Comment: There are plenty of other people submitting good quality research to viXra apart from me. E.g. Mathematician Simon Plouffe has a number of papers on viXra. In fact 5% of submissions come from .edu or other academic domain email addresses and there are plenty of good papers from outside academia. For what its worth about 20% of our content is published in peer-reviewed journals according to an independent report. I know it doesn't fit the narrative but those are the facts.

Comment: The number of good papers in viXra may be lower but there are enough to make it worth having

Comment: @PhilipGibbs Do you have a link for that report? (this seems like a good thing to include in your answer also).

Comment: Correction - it was 15% not 20%. Here is the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1036  There is also a copy of it on viXra at http://vixra.org/abs/1211.0026 .

Comment: @PhilipGibbs The linked paper looked at 20 papers on each repository, and the numbers are based on those papers. The study is also from 2012, at which point viXra had existed for about 3 years. Citing this as 15% of the material on viXra being published seems too strong.

Comment: Yes, given more time it is probably higher now, but the precise figure is not really important. The fact that any is successfully peer-reviewed counters the claim that it is all crank material.

Comment: I think this answer is unusually harsh on viXra

Answer (score 3):

[viXra.org](http://vixra.org/) (arXiv spelled backwards) was founded in response to [the many reports of arXiv.org's censorship](http://www.archivefreedom.org/casehistories.htm), victims of which include Nobel Prize laureates and first-class university professors. See their "[Why viXra?](http://vixra.org/why)" page.

[ArchiveFreedom.org](http://www.archivefreedom.org/) (cf. their book [*Against the Tide*](http://www.archivefreedom.org/freedom/againsttide.pdf)) has collected [dozens of such case studies of censorship](http://www.archivefreedom.org/casehistories.htm), which they introduce by saying:

> In reporting these case histories we do not imply that we are embracing, supporting or endorsing, in any way, the particular ideas, work, principles, or religious and personal beliefs of these scientists.  Our aim is to include a wide range of victims, scientists from all over the world, who range from Nobel Prize winners to relatively unknown scientists, those with numerous publications in first rate journals, to those with a few publications in second rate journals, from professors in first class universities to humble scientists working outside academia, from rigorous scientists to those exploring the fringes of science.

Also:

> The New Endorsement System: Merely a Smoke Screen
>
> In January 2004, arXiv.org introduced an automated endorsement system which was touted by operators of the system as an answer to complaints about the archive's restrictive policies.   However, there have been cases where blacklisted scientists have attempted to use this supposedly objective endorsement system and the outcome has been overriden to ensure that their works are still blocked.
>
> Another drawback is that most endorsers are fearful of endorsing novel papers because they worry that they could lose their endorser status if their decision runs counter to the tastes of the arXiv moderators.  In fact, the arXiv.org website states that the archive administrators reserve the right to revoke any endorser's endorsement status.  When one blacklisted scientist's paper was rejected, the reason given by the archive moderator was: "No legitimate endorsements from current users."  When the scientist then asked "will you guarantee that persons who endorse me will not be victimised by having their arXiv privileges withdrawn?" no substantive response was forthcoming.
>
> The scientist concluded from this that they had refused to guarantee that anyone who endorsed him would not be punished for doing so.  Thus one could surmise that the endorsement system is merely a facade to give the false impression that the electronic preprint archive operates in a fair manner.

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the differences. Should we do a search for other questions related to arXiv, so you have more places to paste this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Publishing pre-prints of your scientific papers gives you the following opportunities:

1. You can confirm your authorship
2. Your work becomes available online (so you can share it for academic or job purposes)
3. Collaboration (you can improve your work chatting with colleagues)

According to these principles, one may prefer one e-print archive to another. Here're the reasons why you should or shouldn't choose viXra (change the sign to get information about arXiv).

Reasons to publish on viXra:

1. The publishing process is fast (plus for 2 and 1)
2. Papers on viXra are easy-structured (plus for 3)

Reasons not to publish on viXra:

1. Bad reputation (minus for 3)
2. The site doesn't seem to be professional (minus for 2)

Thus, generally, one may say that viXra is preferable in the sense of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these negative answers are misleading. viXra can be very useful if you just want to post a paper easily, and share among a small group, or be able to prove priority.

As a source for browsing pre-prints, the quality is very variable, so you might find only about one paper in ten is scientifically interesting, depending on the field.

viXra has a very useful point, because:

1. it is a useful service for many people;
2. it allows a diversity of ideas;
3. if you have academic enemies they may be able get you barred from posting perfectly legitimate work on arXiv—it is open to academic warfare, which is why viXra was started.

However, if you want to advertise your work to mainstream academics, then viXra has very little attention, while most scientists browse preprints on arXiv. (I post some work on viXra to support it as a matter of principle—as it is attacked by bullies—although I get far more real interest from posts on other preprint sites.)