# Is viXra a good site for e-prints

Tags: publications, preprint, website

ViXra.org is a host site for e-prints similar to Arxiv.org. I wonder if ViXra is a good place for posting e-prints and how well it is known to the scientific communities.

Comment: It is known but does not have a particularly good reputation. Check also the Wikipedia page on that for more information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No it is not a good place.  In fact it is infamous in the community.

While not everything there is crackpot, almost everything there is crackpot.  It has the well-deserved reputation of being the very last outpost for those who are turned away everywhere else.

Comment: +1  "viXra, the last outpost" - sounds like the perfect movie title for the next movie about zombie research(ers) stranded on a planet for derelict science.

Comment: *While not everything there is crackpot, almost all the crackpot stuff is there.* --- There is a huge amount of crackpot stuff [on the internet] that is NOT there. What you mean is: "While not everything there is crackpot, almost everything there is crackpot."

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I edited my answer to plagiarize you much better formulation.

Comment: Incidentally, for proof that "not everything there is crackpot", see the comments to [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/105520/49593). However, my guess is that less than 0.1% falls into this category.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro yes it would be too sweeping to suggest *everything* is crackpot on vixra.

Comment: Taking a break from work (contract, at home), I spent the last 20-25 minutes surfing through math papers in viXra, something I haven't done in several years I think. I managed to find a few papers that are clearly more than just non-crackpot -- [these papers](https://vixra.org/author/bulat_n_khabibullin), and [this paper](https://vixra.org/pdf/1412.0024v1.pdf) which was published in the [Amer. Math. Monthly](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642006), and probably most of [these papers](https://vixra.org/author/m_caldas) although they seem to me mostly low quality citation-purposed papers.