# When to submit to viXra (rather than arXiv or not at all)?

Tags: arxiv, preprint

[arxiv](https://arxiv.org/) has the description:

> arXiv is a free distribution service and an open-access archive for 2,146,943 scholarly articles in the fields of physics, mathematics, computer science, quantitative biology, quantitative finance, statistics, electrical engineering and systems science, and economics. Materials on this site are not peer-reviewed by arXiv.

[viXra](https://vixra.org/) has the description:

> An alternative archive of 39635 e-prints in Science, Mathematics & Other Scholarly Areas serving the whole scientific community

I have anecdotally heard that "viXra is a venue for crackpots to publish their bad ideas". I don't know if that is strictly true, but I was shown some highly speculative and low-quality papers that exemplify that there are low-quality submissions on viXra.

Even so, **is there a use case for submitting to viXra?**

---

To show effort, I have tried to brainstorm some possibilities and some countering points of view to using viXra.

Here are some speculations of use cases:

- Failed simulations, experiments, or attempted proofs: something went wrong, and you cannot use the results. But you can describe what you did and the outcomes, and speculate on what went wrong. Maybe someone could learn from your mistakes.
- Not a substantial contribution: you produce some statistics on an easily-collected data set showing an unsurprising result. Or similarly prove some mathematical results that are technically novel but would be considered obvious by professional mathematicians (e.g. found the derivative or integral of a function which didn't require much insight).
- Course replication experiments: You're a student, and you've done an experiment following laboratory protocols provided by your lab instructor. If you had done this experiment 100 years ago it would have been ground-breaking research, but yours is just a modern replication. You've done an excellent job, it just isn't remotely new.
- Bottom-of-the-ladder: No one else will accept your submission. Maybe you are a crackpot, or maybe you are not. But you've tried everything you were willing to try, and this is you sending out your message in a bottle.

Some counter attitudes:

- The chances that the above provide value are low, so don't clutter the internet with them.
- If you do something of value, put it somewhere people will notice. Otherwise don't bother.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between viXra.org and arXiv.org?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/105518/what-are-the-differences-between-vixra-org-and-arxiv-org)

Comment: In particular, this is a good answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/105520/13240

Comment: I'd add to the counter attitudes that putting your work on vixra can harm your reputation, by associating you with a lot of cranks.