How does one go about writing papers as a nobody?
To begin with, I have no credentials, no degrees, no references, and no certificates. I haven't even started university.
However, I still want to write a paper, for two main reasons.

The people reviewing my college application will see something nice if they happen to search for my name.
Bragging rights.

Is this at all a possibility or just a pipe dream? If it's a possibility, where do I get started? I had a look at a few papers from a few different fields, and I don't think I have nearly enough knowledge to make serious contributions to mathematics, and obviously, I can't do experimental research. I have been considering meta-analysis; I just need a little bit of statistics knowledge for that, right?
I'm also not sure where I would publish my paper in the end. Would journals even accept a publication from a nobody, and if not, is publishing it on arXiv sufficient?

It seems unlikely that you will be able to do this, given that you don't even seem to have a field in mind. Meta-analysis of what? And do you have enough statistics knowledge to do meta-analysis to a publishable standard? Journals do accept papers from "independent researchers" so that is not a problem. Publishing on Arxiv might impress someone but you will have to be "endorsed" by someone before you can do that.

You should find something you enjoy and want to tell other people about, pick up a Writers Market book, pick your audience, write an article, and submit it.  Repeat until in press.  This may or may not be an academic work.

Regrettably you have been misled about the merits of what you propose. Nobody will mistake you for some undiscovered genius, they will roll their eyes and ignore what is largely a "cringey" contribution. Why? Because there is now a market for vanity publications which have managed to convince high school students that they need a publication to get into college, or that somehow that looks good. It really does not. Do not fall prey to it. The world does not need more low-quality vanity literature that does nothing but line the pockets of low quality, non-academic publishers.

Consider https://vixra.org, which has much less stringent requirements than https://arxiv.org. And first see https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/189900/ for more detailed discussion of vixra versus arxiv. Googling vixra will also cough up a variety of such discussions.

"I just need a little bit of statistics knowledge for that, right?" well, if an "achievement" is trivial, you wouldn't get any credit for the "achievement" to begin with. I feel like you're motivated by all the wrong things here.

More a suggestion than an answer but .... most of us usually who were in that situation went for co-authorship, or credit, with someone of slightly higher standing, rather than trying to get published directly on our own merit.

With all due respect, you seem to have it backwards: The general order is to have something to contribute first (an idea, a result), and then publish that.

@eigengrau Even if the OP wants a publication for the wrong reasons, using vixra is a terrible suggestion. Stickynotememo, vixra exists for publications that can't make it through arxiv's stringent peer review...in spite of the fact that arxiv doesn't have peer review. Vixra is only for crackpots and people who have been duped into thinking it's not just for crackpots (and real scientists who just want to read something hilariously bad (e.g. 1, 2)). Don't be either of those people.

It is bad enough that current academic culture makes academics publish at a rate that is dictated by metrics used for career advancement rather than by what they have to say. Don’t add to that.

@eigengrau I second Ray's comment on vixra. For OP: similar to predatory journals, vixra has a reputation where including it can be detrimental to the appearance of your competence. And for context, the two papers linked to are so bad that it is hard for me not to believe they are parodies of bad papers.

Think of it like this: If just was easy or just a little bit of statistics knowledge was enough everyone could do it, if everyone could do it probably a lot of people would and if a lot of people did it than why would someone by impressed by it? It would be like "having bragging rights" for being able to whistle, sure many people can't do it but it's not really something worth bragging about since quite a lot can anyway

Are you in high school or have you graduated, @stickynotememo? If you're in high school, you may have opportunities you could take advantage of; science fairs are a good way to demonstrate an understanding of the research process without publishing. (And if your research is, indeed, journal quality, you could make connections who could help you publish.) And there may be some summer research programs you could apply to, or you may be able to get in contact with local professors who might be interested. (If you've graduated, there may be opportunities to demonstrate research in the workplace.)

Many top tier computer science conferences have adopted a double blind review process. So, being a 'nobody' shouldn't be a problem

When I was in high school I spent a year working in a neuroscience lab. We ultimately published something in NIPS and I was one of the authors. My advice is to understand where your passion lies, find a professor at a university nearby to work with, and you might be able to publish with them. I'm not commenting on the  motivation being purely for the sake of admissions, just suggesting how the outcome can be achieved.

If what you put on arXiv is worthless to scholars then no, it won't be sufficient. And you need an account there first and that, I believe, still requires an endorser from academia.
Before you write a paper you need something to write about. Before that can reasonably happen you need the background in the topic that will make it feasible. Unlike fiction, where imagination and some writing skill may be enough, academic publishing requires (usually) deep understanding of some topic, even a very narrow topic.
To get the background in the topic you probably need the guidance that a good education should (hopefully) provide. Some, but few, of us can do without that guidance.
You shouldn't even try to publish dreck. It won't do you any good and the response from reviewers will be humbling.
I suggest that you get yourself into a good university, work hard, and pay attention there. One "trick" you might employ is to keep a notebook of ideas that you  think are worth following up on later. Periodically review and update your notebook as you learn more. If you are persistent, and lucky, something might emerge from your efforts. But it takes effort, not just hope. Good luck.
And note that it isn't so much that you are a "nobody", but that you currently lack sufficient background and knowledge to do a good job. Everyone (nearly) starts out as a nobody. You become "somebody" by doing a good job.

Yes, do keep a notebook (paper or electronic) of ideas...

I largely agree with Buffy's answer, but I want to emphasize something else. The OP writes that they want "bragging rights" and to make their college application look better. This is exactly the kind of situation that predatory journals (sometimes called "vanity press") prey on. The OP (and other readers) should be aware of a few things:

When you are just starting out, it's hard to tell if a journal is predatory or not (see: 1, 2, 3, 4)

Such journals will publish your work (for a fee) even if it's crummy. This might give you bragging rights, but only to people who don't know the difference between predatory and reputable journals. Similarly, it gives you a line on your application/resume, and might convince an undergrad admissions officer (though, I think that's unlikely, as very few high school students publish research papers), but you would regret it later.

Having published in a predatory journal looks bad forever. The long-term negatives far outweigh any short term positives.


The nature of academia is to do things the right way, even if it's painful and takes a long time. Academics who take shady shortcuts (like, falsifying their data) even when facing strong external pressures, do not succeed. It's essential to resist the temptation to take such a path. You'll feel better about yourself and your successes if publications are actually earned, which means starting out with years of study, as Buffy recommended.

Although I agree largely with this, in agreement with the accepted answer to the linked question I don't think having published in a predatory journal seriously hurts a CV or a person's reputation. There are just too many legitimate researchers who do this before collecting more experience. (It's not much to brag about either, though.)

@Christian Hennig: Also, if the OP is applying to a U.S. university (to begin undergraduate work), it's very likely that no one looking over the application would know the difference between a cited publication in Annals of Mathematics and a cited publication in a predatory journal, nor will anyone have the slightest understanding of what the paper deals with (unless it deals with some sort of "generalist topic"). Instead, the significance of having a publication would be what letters of recommendation and other supporting documents say about the paper.

The linked answer to 3. States the exact opposite of what you are citing it for.

"Academics who take shady shortcuts (like, falsifying their data) even when facing strong external pressures, do not succeed." - is obviously incorrect. There are so many cases of people being considered great scientists for decades based on full-on fraudulent work that it is basically certain that many people get away with shady practices for their entire career (likely some not even realizing the shadiness, because "that's how we do it here"). It is a bad thing to do and likely does not lead to happy life, but it can definitely lead to "success" by academia's standards.

"I want to make a film. I never made a movie, directed a play, managed people and have no idea what to make the movie about" - this would be the analogy of what you talk about.
Most filmmakers may have, before they studied, had a history of playing with cameras, experimented with settings or staged miniature plays etc. They might have an idea what they would like their first film and story to be about. Their first attempt may not be fully professional, but it has the hallmark of individual energetic enthusiasm about it.
And thus is it with academia. Don't just write a paper. A paper is the end result of something you want to understand and pursue. It does not have to be deep or complicated, but it should be something you are deeply interested in investigating with purpose. The paper is just the documentation of this work and your communication to others about it.
Do not write papers as frivolous exercise. There is enough useless text to go around. Write a paper because you have something to say.
Unless that condition holds, you are wasting your and the readers' time. If doing the above is not what makes your heart beat faster, do employ your time more profitably.

Nice analogy. The history of toying around and collecting experience that way is apparent in Spielberg's The Fabelmans. Something else is also apparent: An irrepressible, visceral drive to make films. That can be observed in many great artists (there is the story of Gillian Lynne as told by Ken Robinson in the most famous TED talk...)

I like the analogy, but there is maybe a caveat on this answer, which is that with social media like youtube and tiktok, an untrained high school student plausibly could make a successful video on their own. It would definitely take an unusual amount of drive and a very good idea. But, I would argue that even an unusually high amount of drive and a good idea plus access to an internet distribution venue like arxiv is not enough for a beginner to write a good academic paper.

@Andrew Even with a video, OP needs to have an idea what they want to do. Otherwise, yes, there are lots of novel media on offer to be used.

The short answer to your question (as the other fine answer already say) is basically, no, this is not feasible unless you are a prodigy genius on the order of Mozart or Orson Welles or Terence Tao.  And, statistically, you're not.  I don't say that to be mean, or discouraging-- factually, neither am I.  Those people are really rare.
I do want to emphasize things a little differently, though.
You're sort of putting the cart before the horse, here.
Academia-- meaning, a somewhat traditional passage through an undergraduate degree, maybe a masters degree, maybe some years in industry, and then a PhD-- is one path by which people learn to do the research activities that lead to scholarly papers.
Those activities are skills.  They can be taught and they can be learned, but they depend (in this context) on a broad and deep base of existing knowledge that typically takes years of intense guided study to acquire.  Usually by years of study or experience.
What you're trying to do is invert the process and turn the act of writing a scholarly paper into part of the admissions process to the very place you will start to acquire that knowledge and those skills.
I don't want you to feel bad about this misapprehension.  Other answers are absolutely correct that there are little predatory outfits pitching these ideas, preying on insecurities and egos.  (Indeed, one of the things you learn in postgraduate education is how to recognize these outfits, and as a senior PhD candidate I had to guide several masters students through that process myself.)
But I also don't want you to labor under this misapprehension, either.
This just isn't something you're expected to do, because it isn't really within your grasp.
Yet.

Given the content of your posting, I am going to assume that you are currently attending high school or some equivalent thereof. It is certainly possible for high school students to write scientific papers, but it is rare; writing a scientific paper requires producing some novel findings in some academic field, which requires knowing what has been done before on that subject. High school students mostly simply have not had enough time to reach that stage, and to gain the additional experience that is needed to then find something new. Additionally, writing a scientific paper is a lot of work even when the scientific work has been done. In the context of your posting, I don't think "bragging rights" provide the required intrinsic motivation; but I could be wrong about that. Ideally, scientific work starts with a question that you intrinsically want to see answered and that nobody can as yet answer.
If one sets the bar a bit lower than fully professional-level research, then it is perfectly possible for a small publication to emerge naturally from something at the level of a very well executed high school science competition project. There are some journals that publish specifically research at that level. While the concern raised in other answers about predatory publishers is valid, I disagree with those answers when they claim that it is difficult to recognize predatory publishers at that level. Predatory publishers will charge a significant fee for publishing, whereas non-predatory journals won't; in addition, they'll be backed by institutions with serious research involvement and some link to the cause of fostering research at the high school level. In the German language area, for instance the journal "Junge Wissenschaft" comes to mind (which has links to a national high-school level science competition and backing by the National Metrology Institute). I'm confident similar journals exist in other relatively large countries as well; a teacher and/or a language model of your choice may help you find them. Looking at projects published in such a venue could give you some inspiration for what a project that you could feasibly start yourself might look like (and will also give you a sense of the work factor such projects entail).
I don't think that you are correct in your assumption that doing interesting experimental work is out of reach of high school students in principle. With support from a mentor (for instance, a teacher, or ideally a teacher who in turn is liaising with a researcher) it is quite feasible for an intelligent, motivated and tenacious high school student to run for instance computational experiments or local (e.g. historical or environmental) research that could be of some interest to professionals. However, help by a mentor and/or some suitable organisational scaffolding (for instance, doing the work as part of a science competition) would be very beneficial for such a project, and of the aforementioned qualities of the student, I would rate tenacity the highest.

Open-access journals charge "a significant fee" - it may be hard for a high schooler to distinguish these based on your heuristic.

Yes, that's true. But as far as I can tell, it's not true for non-predatory journals aimed at publishing student research. I think using common sense and some public resources, a high schooler can recognize those reliably.

Your description of your academic stature indicates that you have no education or achievements at a high enough level to write anything at all which would be taken seriously by anyone. You really don't want to start writing papers at this level because you won't impress anyone. In any case, the function of a paper is not to impress people but to extend the mass of knowledge already available to the world (you will soon be found out if you try to do it without knowledge, because there are an awful lot of people out there who know much more than you do, on any given topic). Work hard to win a university place. When you have one, work hard again to gain a high-level degree (a mere pass for turning up won't do it). Then work hard to gain a Masters and then a Doctorate (or skip the Masters if you're good enough). By then, you should have gained enough knowledge and experience in your chosen field to have the kind of ideas which can be developed into a paper. Remember that an academic paper is not simply a matter of regurgitating other people's ideas. Neither is it a matter of pure opinion; you'll need a lot of hard learning at your fingertips in order to construct a credible piece of writing. You need to know your topic inside out so that you can read and defend your paper(s) at conferences, etc (the ability to defend what you write is absolutely essential if you are to avoid humiliation). You have a long row to hoe in front of you. Good luck.


Is this at all a possibility or just a pipe dream? If it's a possibility, where do I get started?

Here’s some advice geared towards the practical side of your question. To publish research you need to have some new knowledge to contribute beyond what is currently known. And to discover new knowledge, you necessarily need to bring your own state of knowledge to the edge of what is known. It is only from the edge of knowledge that new knowledge can be discovered. Just like in the age of geographical exploration, a would-be explorer could not hope to “publish” new geographical discoveries by sitting in their home town in some European country where every inch of land has been thoroughly mapped and known for centuries. Explorers literally had to venture to the edge of the known physical world and then step beyond that.
So, if you want to publish, go in some direction that will take you to the edge of knowledge. Once you get there, look beyond the edge.
Fortunately, with knowledge, there are many more “directions” one can go in to reach the edge than in the world of physical exploration. Any intellectual area of thought or study is a suitable direction: e.g., 18th century poets; the mating behavior of butterflies; or almost anything else you can think of.
Since you are interested in mathematics, even in that discipline there are almost unlimited directions you can go in to reach the edge of knowledge, including some relatively young and unexplored ones where one does not have to go very far to reach the edge of what is known. But even for those areas, typically at least 1-3 years of concentrated study (relative to the state of knowledge of a high school graduate) are probably needed to reach the edge of knowledge. Form a plan of action for how you will study enough to get to the edge of knowledge, and then carry it out. A university degree (and in some cases a graduate degree after that) is probably the most standard route to get there, but reading books on your own, even watching YouTube videos or using other educational media that are freely available out there, can work for some people or at least get you part of the way there.
Good luck, and happy exploring!

Go for it - with a few adjustments.
University admissions are difficult because they are faced with a lot of indistinguishable candidates who are not people yet, may become people one day or may not. The traditional method of “take all the applications to the fourth floor, throw them into the stairwell, and accept the ones that land on the second floor” is as reliable as any other procedure, and faster.
Given that, it is good to aim for non-indistinguishability. At the very least it will give them something to talk to you about at interview.
Completely abandon any idea of advancing the course of human knowledge. Or of Getting Published as a kind of endorsement. As other answerers have said, that only leads to fake journals.
Here is what to do.
Start a blog. This can be done free on many platforms, from Wordpress to blogger to I don’t know what.
Aim for an audience of 1 - you. Write posts that you want to read. Do not seek or hope for approval from anyone else.
You will not add to the sum of human knowledge, so don’t try.
What you can do is find topics from a field that interests you. Not even necessarily one you are planning to study. Let’s say it’s astronomy. Let’s say that you are interested in the way that planets are said to “capture” satellites, which (you think) doesn’t make sense because the way orbits work, “whatever falls inwards is going to fall outwards again just as fast”.
You now have curiosity. And you have a puzzle. Look into it on SE and elsewhere. Write an article which summarises what you see as the problem - whether you think people are addressing or ignoring it - what approaches you have seen - whether they seem to fit together or make sense at all - what advances you as a spectator would hope to see in, say, 5 years.
Expository writing is a very valuable skill. Moreover you can tell yourself that if you aren’t advancing human knowledge, you are advancing human understanding… which is better.
Your main audience is you, now, and the satisfaction you get from reading it. Your second audience is you, in five years’ time. Your third audience is anyone else who happens to see what you have written.
In terms of university entrance, you will have

Shown a body of work not a freak article.
Shown you are able to work persistently and long term.
Shown that you are interested without being told to be interested.
Shown that you are into a subject because of the subject and not because someone wrote it into a syllabus.
Shown that as a student you will not just sit there saying “tell me what to think now”.
Shown that you have matured beyond thinking that the task of the scholar is to “get the right answer.”

Plus - if you end up writing intelligently enough, you will be able to write to researchers and ask them questions about their work. They love answering.
Above all, you will get practice in writing papers.
Go for it - and post a link here!

The other answers are directly answering your question about writing a paper. I just want to say I agree, but also suggest there are ways of accomplishing your underlying goal of standing out on a college application without writing a paper. I am assuming you are a high school student, and are located in the US, mainly because that is the system I have the most experience with.
First, make sure you have excellent grades and recommendations from your teachers. If you do not have those, generally I think your time would be better spent working toward those goals, then extracurricular academics.
Second, many subjects have academic competitions. For example, in math there are Mathletes or the Olympiad. Competing and doing well in those is a way to prove your mathematical ability. Or there may be science fairs.
Third, if your school has an option to do a senior project or thesis, take that option. Work with your teacher to stretch your project a little bit beyond what a typical high schooler would do, but not so much that you can't do a good job.
For example, I worked with a high school student who wrote a short review of evidence for dark matter and summarized some modern research. Was it a publishable academic article? No. If I were to judge it as a research review article, I would say it cherry picked the literature, misunderstood some issues, and did not give a comprehensive survey of a coherent part of the field. But was it an impressive job for a high schooler working mostly independently? Absolutely. And it showed passion for the subject that has great potential to develop with formal education. This kind of work can seep into your resume, personal statement, recommendations, ... So it is worthwhile and shows you are passionate.
Now, life isn't fair, so not everyone will be able to do point three. However, you can take advantage of the resources you have. If you are in a situation where you can contact a professor and have them give you a small project as a high school thesis, that can look really cool! Even though it almost certainly will not lead to a paper. But even if you aren't, you can do a lot of very cool projects on your own with limited funding. Get a raspberry pi and put one a drone and see what you can get it to do. One impressive high school science fair project I judged created a phased array of microphones by sending signals to off-the-shelf speakers with a laptop running Matlab.
Finally, due to social media, with youtube, and TikTok, and so on, there actually are ways to show off and publicize your ideas/inventions, even if they aren't publishable by strict, academic standards. Making a youtube video about the self-flying drone you built could be a really cool way to show off your skills in science and communication and would be a doable-if-difficult project for a high schooler.
To summarize, what I'm saying is that there are developmentally appropriate ways to show your creativity and stand out on a college application, that are accessible even if you don't have access to a research lab (but if you do have access to a research lab, you can use that kind of connection as well). You don't need to write a paper, and trying to do so will almost certainly backfire, because you need a lot of education and training to reach the point where you can do that. Work with your teachers, pick something more manageable, and you can absolutely find a way to show off your passion in a way that goes beyond a standard high school curriculum.

As with all other answers, you don't have the capacity to do research yet. Generally the research required for a paper will take several months of (about) full time work, followed by a number of months of writing the work up. If this is done independently this is following about a decade of full time learning after completing high school to reach this competency. If this is done with a supervisor, it generally requires about a completed undergraduate degree (and this can still be closer to answering an assignment sheet than doing real research).
Regarding meta-analysis, that might actually be harder that doing original research. Its a lot of statistics, yes, but it also requires you to be able to read all the papers you put into the analysis and understand them, where their limitations are, are they comparable to other papers in the field. If you don't know the field well enough to answer those questions, your results would be less informative than reading just one of the papers used in the meta-analysis.
You seem to be avoiding non-flashy fundamentals for flashy auxiliaries. Non-crackpot researchers have learnt all the fundamentals through their undergraduate/masters level coursework. Focus on the fundamentals first, do you have the education to be enrolled at the university. Then ask yourself: what excites you? And use that to decide on any flashy additions you want to add. These shouldn't be things just to get into a university (external motivation), but something that you would be driven to do (intrinsic motivation). Your question suggests your motivation for doing research is the first and not the second. So I'd suggest, ask yourself what you want to do/what you enjoy doing and find a way to leverage that drive into something productive that could be added to any applications you put together.

I don't like the discouraging answers here, so I am taking a different tack. I think you should find a place where you want to submit a paper, and download their template on overleaf, or similar tool. Read some papers in your chosen field to narrow down your scope, and start experimenting.
The key for you is to understand how to conduct scientific analysis and research, and the expected format of publishing in conferences or journals.
Many high school students have published, so it is not out of the ordinary. Usually, their parents or someone else in their lives helps connect them to a mentor at an institution where they can get some kind of directed guidance. However, don't fret if you don't have that kind of connection. It will make it harder, but not impossible.
If all else fails, take your findings and publish them in a blog post and share widely. Once you have some blog post, you can even use that to reach out to a professor or scientist who you think might be interested.
Update--I'll make some amendments based on the comments on this reply. I think the commenters are wrong because it's not their place to decide what someone can do, only OP can decide that. OP simply asked for advice on where to start. My comment didn't really answer that well either, so I hope OP or someone similar can find the follow up more helpful.
Per my experience, a reasonable place to start is by reading other papers and finding an interesting question or two to form hypotheses around. You can also just read technical blog posts, and start asking yourself "what if" questions. Then you start experimenting by exploring your "what if" questions.
Maybe make a small slide deck of your experiments and observations to keep track of your activities. You'll go back and forth in this process because it's never a straight line. But that's no reason to be discouraged, unless what you're doing is fundamentally wrong or foolish. This is where it helps to have someone more experienced than you have a look at what you're doing.
I'll state more explicitly that your goal really shouldn't be publishing, but learning how to conduct scientific investigations. The goal of publishing is to share knowledge and findings in a standard way so others can build off what you've found. If you're just starting out, then learn how to carry out and appreciate the scientific process.
But more importantly, learn to respectfully disagree with people who disagree with you. It doesn't matter what anyone else thinks you can do, what matters is what you think.
To the commenters who are being discouraging to a young person, I'll say simply this--please, don't. It's the domain of the young to be impractical. I think you can just guide someone as best as you can, but never actually say no unless that person is doing something fundamentally wrong.

Actually, high school students publishing is rather dramatically "out of the ordinary". Few do so. And, when they do, we usually consider it "extraordinary".

@Buffy you have to be a bit careful about that. I've seen at least the following report on companies that are trying to cheese that idea for undergrad admissions. https://www.propublica.org/article/college-high-school-research-peer-review-publications

If all else fails, take your findings and publish them in a blog post and share widely. What makes this answer unhelpful is that OP has no “findings”, nor any idea how to find findings - that’s kind of exactly what the question is about (“where do I get started?”). But you haven’t addressed that at all, instead basing your answer on the premise that OP has the ability to do research and just needs to get it published.

"Download a template from Overleaf" as the first step is very odd advice. -1
